# JS Detect the native resolution of a display (4K)

Tags: javascript, native, resolution, detection, monitor

Is there a way to detect if a monitor is a 4K display?

I need a solution that will recognize the native/ highest possible resolution of a display. So if it is a 4K display, but the display-settings have been changed to 1920x1080 and some zoom-factor (e.g. 200%,  changed in the windows display-settings)- I'd need to know that is a 4K-display allthough the available window-size is 1920x1080 max.

`window.screen.availWidth`  and  `window.devicePixelRatio`  won't work for that as they are only looking at the avai

Comment: You can't, screen size only goes as far as what the OS display server tells the browser. You'd need NodeJS to dig into the availible resolutions to extract that information, meaning it's impossible with front-end technology